# Extract the real value of the relationship lookup field in soql

Tags: salesforce, soql

I'm a newbie to soql relationship queries. I've been trying to to get this working but not sure if this is even possible.

```
Select Id, Name, CustomObject__r.name From Account where customobject__c != null
```

Gives me a result that has a column of 'customobject__c', but which I have to click on to see the real value. I want to see the real value in the table, so that I can extract it to a csv. CustomObject is a lookup field in Account.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a better SOQL editor. What are you using at the moment?

Data Loader (officially supported tool) should give you these full relationship "path names" when you export data but it's a bit too clunky to be used on daily basis. You'd be designing your queries in one tool and pasting them to DL...

I'm a big fan of RealForceExplorer ;) See [How to add comments in SOQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13527752/how-to-add-comments-in-soql) for some hints and pick your favorite editor.

[image: RFE example]

Comment: I am using DataLoader and Force.com Explorer. Thank you for the answer and suggestion. I will try this out.

Comment: My query in RealForceExplorer works like a charm :-) Dziekuje!

Comment: Ależ proszę bardzo, panie Tomaszu :P